# connecting from hadoop to google cloud storage via service account key stored as gitlab CICD variable

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, service-accounts

I have generated a service account keyfile which contains an ID for the key as well as the (rather lengthy) key iself.

I'd like to store this automatically in gitlab CICD preferably, where the process itself can do one of two things (neither of which I have conceptualized)

1. Pass the CICD variable in as another nested variable which the host machine in subsequent workflows will maintain so the key, stored as a string as a $variable, can be passed in as the value of this argument:
   `-D fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key="${variable}`
2. (in CICD prep) check for the existence of a file, and if not, create a file and (somehow) inject the value of the CICD variable into such a file, and then call it once more from subsequent scripts safely and then use the output of that file as a value to the same argument above (hadoop command)
   `-D fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key="${/path/to/file?}`
   The above of course does not work. (Invalid arguments: Invalid PKCS8 data)

EDIT: I should also add that this instance of gitlab is not associated with google cloud and the project I am making is attempting to use google services remotely with use of service accounts

Comment: 1) You must set `fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key` to the value of the key `private_key` from the service account JSON file. Don't forget to also set `fs.gs.auth.service.account.email` and `fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id`. Most likely you are corrupting the `private_key` value. Extract `private_key`, base64 encode and store that value as a variable (a secret is better). Then when you read the value base64 decode it so the private key value will not be corrupted. 2) You cannot do this `fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key="${/path/to/file` as a filename is not expected.

Comment: Does @Jhon Hanley’s comment solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that's what I've been doing all this time but I am wondering what the best way is to handle the storage of this key/value. If I store as a gitlab variable what is a best practice for preserving the usage of this key in a subsequent scheduled script that will run long after the project is deployed via gitlab?